# Nanohttpd or Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, server

Long time lurker but first time poster. I've been asking myself a simple question but one that I can't seem to sufficiently answer. Recently, I've been given a project where I would have to put a html server onto an android tablet. My initial search yielded Nanohttpd and I followed through with that. Now, I realized that it might have been possible to node.js. Could someone give me a quick comparison and a recommendation? It seems like both could be use if I'm not wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How does one make a web server with Node.js?

Comment: This is the example tutorial I've been following.
http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs